# Improper Excel Profit Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm looking to include in column H of my spreadsheet as profit as a %. Such as if you paid $5, and sold for $10, you made 200% profit or 2x your money, obviously excel will only recognize 200%, not 2x. But I am getting some crazy numbers, so obviously I'm not doing something right. Column B is what I paid, and Column F is what I sold it for.

@ Gary's Student, This is a good formula, but for my first example, Paid $1, sold for $50, my percentage comes out as 4900%? Everyone after that comes out correct.

Comment: What is the formula you have, and what are the "crazy numbers"? Is there some reason e.g. `=F1/B1` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @ Gary's Student, This is a good formula, but for my first example, Paid $1, sold for $50, my percentage comes out as 4900%? Everyone after that comes out correct.

Comment: Buying for $5 and selling for $10 is a 100% profit, not 200%. (You make $5 in the end when subtracting the $5 paid from the $10 received, and $10 is 100% more than $5, hence 100% profit.) The sell price in that case however *is* 200% *of* the purchase price, but that's not the same thing. In calculating profit you need to take cost into account.

Comment: If you are getting 4900% then you have probably left out the parentheses from the formula. 50-1/1 = 49 which, when formatted as a percentage in Excel, will be 4900%. You want to calculate (50-1)/1, not 50-1/1.

Comment: @ Mike Fitzpatrick, I do have the parentheses around the calculation, and I am still getting the 4900%. The proper profit % should be 490%. Not sure why there is an extra zero.

Comment: Sorrit, it was late when I wrote that - the answer is the same regardless of the parentheses when buy price is $1. 4900% sounds correct to me now. If you buy for $1 and sell for $50 then your profit is 49x the buy price (4900%).

Answer (score 2):

Use a better formula:

```
Percent Profit = (Sell Price-Purchase Price) / Purchase Price
```

[image]

See:

[Formula for Percentage Profit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105306/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-profit-percentage)

Answer (score 0):

```
=($F2/$B2)*100
```

should do what you want it to

Cases:
[image]

If you then want to tidy it up a bit, simply format the column to 2DP, set it as a percentage etc.  If you want to be really fancy, you can look at doing this within your Formula and use something like:

```
=ROUND(((F5/B5)*100),2)&"%"
```